Colab in Safari - How to copy and paste an entire cell
This is a real beginners question, but how do you copy and paste and entire text cell in Colab? Copy paste contents of a text cell seems to lose format and links. And trying to paste a copy cell just gives the message use ctrl-v.
A previous question here seems to indcate Safari is not great for Colab?
